# Yahoo mail content displaying as base64 string

Tags: email, html-email, mvcmailer, yahoo-mail

I'm using `Mvc mailer` to send Html Emails to external domains, I am able to send mails to all domains

```
var mailMessage = new MvcMailMessage { Subject = "sample mail" };
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.To.Add("test@gmail.com");

var resources = new Dictionary<string, string>();   
resources["logo"] = filePath;
resources["mask"] = maskedpath;

PopulateBody(mailMessage,viewName:"sampleviewname",linkedResources:resources);
```

But for the past few days, I've been having an issue with Yahoo mail. In Yahoo, my mail content is displaying as `base64` string, what is the reason for this?

Are there any changes in Yahoo mail?

**Update :**
If I am trying to decode the `base64` string in yahoo mail body content, I can able to see my html tags. (copied yahoo mail content and added `data:image/jpeg;base64` to content, Now in browser network i can see my html code)

Comment: If you attaching some file, then file content inside mail might be encoded as `base64`. Also, make sure the file is placed inside mail as an attachment.

Comment: but total mail content including text in mail is converted as base64

Comment: Can you show some of the content of mail-body and all the mail-headers?

Comment: @sameerkn please check updated question

Comment: The pertinent headers and a representative - but short - sample of the problematic body part will probably improve your chances of receiving a helpful reply.

Comment: Try specifying `data:text/html;quoted-printable` to content. Also, specify where are you trying to add `data:image/jpeg;base64`, in the `mailMessage` while sending message?

Comment: Also, it seems that mailer is trying to see your content as an attachment which most probably will be encoded as `base64`.

Comment: No @sameerkn, copied the content from the mail which i have received in yahoo and added `data:image/jpeg;base64`, Now in new tab address bar I have pasted this in browser network -> <current request> -> response tab of the browser i can see my view page

Comment: @sameerkn, How can I change this behavior, _mailer is trying to see your content as an attachment_

Comment: Please show the mail-header from the Yahoo WebMail. Specially `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

Comment: @sameerkn, These are the headers of Yahoo WebMail, `Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=--boundary_1_66ca1e59-2cb5-4bc8-afb6-0804e746f2aa; and  type="text/html"` headers doesn't have `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

Comment: Have you set the following `mailMessage` properties: `Body, BodyEncoding, BodyTransferEncoding`. What are they?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114006/discussion-between-buvi-suri-and-sameerkn).